# GWT Generator not called with GIN Injection

Tags: gwt, generator, gwt-gin

I have declared a generator in my GWT module descriptor and it seems it is not called when the class which trigger the generator is instanciated via the Ginjector.

```
public interface MyGinjector extends Ginjector {
  MyWidget getMyWidget();
}


public class MyEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

  public static final MyGinjector INJECTOR = GWT.create(MyGinjector.class);

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    MyWidget myWidget = INJECTOR.getMyWidget(); // [1]
    MyWidget myWidget = GWT.create(MyWidget.class); // [2]
    RootPanel.add(myWidget);
  }

}
```

[1] The generator is not called.
[2] The generator is called.

Does it mean that the GIN injector does not instanciate object through the GWT.create() method?

Thanks for your help.
Kind regards,

Comment: Can you show the source for MyWidget?

Comment: This code looks like the example code from the GIN documentation: http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinTutorial. Although I miss step 4 in your code (adding the @GinModules annotation). If you're looking for samples to start with you might look at the sample project: http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/source/browse/trunk/samples/

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, GIN (at least up until 1.5) will only generate a `GWT.create()` if the class has a public zero-arg constructor *that is not annotated with `@Inject`* (otherwise it'll do a `new` on it)